# variable autocomplete after deletion from env Linux

Tags: linux, zsh

I remove the variable from > env with the > unset command, but the variable appears again after closing the terminal! before it was removed and did not appear after the command > unset.Terminal ZSH.

Comment: Is it possible that there are more env files loaded?

Comment: Hi! this is one variable env, when I delete it with the unset command, this variable disappears, but when I close the terminal and open the terminal again, the variable that I deleted appears again!)

Comment: You probabbly need to disable it in a file called `.zshrc`. Disclaimer: I am no zsh user.

Comment: Thanks) I haven't changed anything in .zshrc

Comment: @wind, as I've said, the variable is most probably loaded from an `env` file when new session is started. I think `unset` is a current-session-only solution, you need to remove that variable from it's source env file.

Comment: I delete the variable from the env file using the command - unset, the editors do not read the env as far as I tried. When I type the env command from under the root, this variable is not visible, but in fact it is.When a new session starts, this variable appears again